# Study the differentiability of $f$ .

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ and hilbert space and  $f(x)=\| x\|$ for all $x\in E$. Study the differentiability of $f$ on $0$ and find $df(x)h$ for all $h\in E$ and $x\neq0$.

**My attempt :**
$f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, in fact consider $E=\mathbb R^n$ and $\|x\|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}=f(x_1,\cdots,x_n).$
$\displaystyle\lim_{x_i \to 0^+} \dfrac {f(0,..,0,x_i,0,..,0)-f(0,\cdots,0)}{x_i}=1$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x_i \to 0^-} \dfrac {f(0,..,0,x_i,0,..,0)-f(0,\cdots,0)}{x_i}=-1$, so $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Let $x\neq 0$, I have proved in a previous question that $ \psi : x \mapsto\|x\|^2$ is differentiable and that $d\psi(x)h=2\langle x,h\rangle$, so $f(x=\sqrt{\psi(x)}=\varphi\circ\psi(x)$ with $\varphi(t)=\sqrt t$ for all $t\geqslant 0$, so  $$df(x)h=d\varphi(\psi(x))\circ d\psi(x)h=\frac{1}{2\|x\|}2\langle x,h\rangle=\langle\frac{x}{\|x\|},h \rangle.$$
Is my attempt correct?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: $df(x)h$ should be understood as $\nabla f \cdot h$, i.e., as the directional derivative, or, more precisely, as the differential of $f$ corresponding, right

Comment: @Physor I think $df(x)$ should be the differential at $x$ as an abstract linear map, here, and $df(x)h$ the aforementioned applied to the vector $h$.

Comment: yes, it is better denoted $Df(x)$ in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{ u_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ each element has a Fourier expansion
$$
x = \sum_k x_k u_k = \sum_k \langle u_k,x \rangle u_k\ ;\qquad x_k = \langle u_k,x \rangle 
$$
which implies
$$
\|x\|^2 \equiv \langle x,x \rangle = \sum_k |x_k|^2
$$
The derivative of the absolute value function (exept at zero) is
$$
\frac{d}{dv}|v|=\frac{v}{|v|} = \begin{cases} +1 & v > 0 \\ -1 & v < 0\end{cases}
$$
The derivative of a real-valued function is a linear map which is specified by its action on the basis vectors. These actions are found by the chain rule (where $x \ne 0$)
$$
Df(x)u_k = \partial_k f(x) = \partial_k \|x\|
\ =\ \partial_k\left(\sum_j |x_j|^2\right)^{1/2}
\ =\ \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_j |x_j|^2\right)^{-1/2}\partial_k\left(\sum_j |x_j|^2\right) \\
\ =\ \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^{-1}\ 2|x_k|\ \partial_k|x_k| 
\ =\ \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^{-1}\ 2|x_k|\ \frac{x_k}{|x_k|}
\ =\ \frac{x_k}{\|x\|}
$$
The derivative of $f$ at $x$ is a (bounded) linear function $Df(x): E \to \mathbb R$, that means that $Df(x) \in E'$,  where $E'$ is the *topological* dual of $E$. By the [**Riesz–Fréchet representation theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) for every bounded linear function (e.g. $Df(x)$) there is one and only one element $T_{Df(x)} \in E$ such that
$$
Df(x)h = \langle T_{Df(x)}, h \rangle\ ; \qquad \forall h \in E
$$
That element is
$$
T_{Df(x)} = \sum_k u_k\ \langle T_{Df(x)}, u_k \rangle\ = \sum_k u_k\ \partial_k f(x) = \sum_k u_k \frac{x_k}{\|x\|} = \frac{x}{\|x\|}
$$
It can be regarded as an element in $E$ (not quite sure for infnite dimensional vector spaces), so one can take the inner product of it with other elements in $E$. For example
$$
Df(x)h \equiv \langle T_{Df(x)}, h\rangle = \frac{1}{\|x\|}\langle x, h\rangle  
$$

Comment: Thank you so much ! I really appreciate your help !                              
 $df(x)h$ in my case is $Df(x)(h)$ (only a problem of notation)

Comment: Please, what theorem do you mean ?

Comment: I mentioned it in the answer, **Riesz-Frechet Theorem** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem

Comment: Ah, thank you again for your help !

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If I were given this question, I would think of "studying the differentiability of $f$ at $0$" as devising a predicate $\mathcal Q$ about Hilbert spaces such that a real Hilbert space $(E,\langle\bullet,\bullet\rangle)$ has $\lVert \bullet\rVert$ differentiable at $0$ if and only if $\mathcal Q(E)$. This is what I may also call a *discussion* of differentiability at $0$ (in some parameters ranging somewhere, in this case the parameter is $E$ ranging over the Hilbert spaces). It seems to me that you have only proved the weaker assertion that there are some Hilbert spaces (namely, $(E,\langle\bullet,\bullet\rangle)$ isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$ for $n\ge1$) such that $\lVert\bullet\rVert$ is not differentiable at $0$. I think you should complete that.

The part for $x\ne 0$ is ok. I don't know, nor can I tell because it's the same, if you're implicitly restricting the discussion to finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces: in that case, I don't see why you should.

Comment: Thank you first for your answer ! 
yes I only show the case of finite dimensional hilbert spaces, but in your opinion how can I show it for the case of infinite dimensional space?                                                 ( excuse me my english is not good enough to express all my ideas )